# Cygwin sshd won't start

Tags: cygwin

Getting the below error msg while starting the cygwin services on windows 2003 server , the SSHD file is showing 0KB.

```
$ net start sshd
The CYGWIN sshd service is starting.
The CYGWIN sshd service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
```

Window's Event Viewer shows the service starting, and then almost immediately after, stopping:

```
The CYGWIN sshd service was successfully sent a start control.

The CYGWIN sshd service entered the stopped state.
```

The Application log again shows the service stopping for a reason I cannot explain:

> The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( sshd ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: sshd: PID 4956: `sshd' service stopped, exit status: 57.

Comment: What happens when you run `/usr/sbin/sshd` from inside Cygwin?

Comment: Did you run `ssh-host-config`?

Comment: we have configured CYGWIN on windows 2008R2 and the services are started when we try to connect from outside to the server it is giving the below error

Answer (score 2):

1. Open a cygwin window as administrator (right click, run as
   administrator)
2. Run /usr/bin/ssh-host-config

   1. new local account ‘sshd’? (yes/no) yes
   2. Do you want to install sshd as a server? yes
   3. Enter the value of CYGWIN for the daemon: [] (DON’T ENTER ANYTHING, PRESS ENTER)
   4. Do you want to use a different name? (yes/no) no
   5. Create new privileged user account ‘cyg_server’? (yes/no) yes
   6. Please enter the password: ENTER YOUR PASSWORD HERE
   7. Reenter: RE-ENTER YOUR PASSWORD
3. cygrunsrv --start sshd

That should do it.  You can test it:

```
ssh -vv localhost
```

If sshd is in fact now running and yet you still can't connect, suspect a firewall.

Comment: I tried to run the bash as administartor but when i right click the bash the option "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR" is not showing only open is showing up , any other way where i can run it as administrator ??

Comment: could anyone please respond on the above query ??

Comment: Certainly - either find the actual bash.exe program in \cygwin\bin or open a CMD prompt as administrator and then subsequently run bash.exe.  If you don't see the option to run bash as administrator you are very likely right clicking on a link to the executable (a shortcut) and not the application itself.

Comment: How goes the battle?

Comment: @vikas - Did you ever make any progress on this?

Comment: first question: Query: Should StrictModes be used? (yes/no) - and: Do you want to install sshd as a service, not `server`